# Escape named parameters in sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a bunch of sqlite3 queries written in a python script, and I used named parameter substitution in all of them. Is there any way to have a named parameter with a space? It would simplify all my queries as my dictionary holds a key with a space. Essentially, is there any way to escape the space in the named parameter in the following query:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (:spaced param)', {'spaced param': 1})
```

Or am I pretty much stuck modifying the keys in my dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

**FOR REFERENCE - sqlite3 doesn't support the following naming style...**

You could use an alternative escape parameter style:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table VALUES (%(spaced param)s)', {'spaced param': 1})
```

Comment: [You can't actually.](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) sqlite3 in python only accepts named or question mark style parameters.

Comment: I have to look it up *every* single time lol. There should really be a standard method for parameter substitution...